# 2009 Boxxer Team Dual Crown - Are springs different from 2010 + models?

Tags: fork, suspension

I have a 2009 boxxer team fork on my bike.  I'd like to buy the firmer spring as I am heavier than the last owner.  Can I put the spring from a 2010/2011/2012 boxxer in there or was there something specific about the spring from 2009 that would require me to find one meant specifically for that year.

I only ask as I can get a really screaming deal on a spring set from a newer boxxer fork.  So if it would work I'd like to go with it.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  Between 2009 and 2010 the stanchion width increased by 3mm (so the spring followed), and the slider end of the 2010 spring is shaped to interface with the bottom of slider - whereas it isn't on the 2009 model.